# UIButton hide when change position in scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I've a scrollView with imageview and semi-transparent button over this image.
The button and the imageview are added to scrollview with [addsubview].
Now I need to change the imageview and button position (changing the frame property)

es:

```
button.frame = CGRectMake( x, y, w, h );
```

after I do this the button hides. If I change only the button position it work perfectly.

PS: I've just tried to use bringtofront.

the scrollview content creation:

```
   int index = 0;
    int x = OFFSETXCOPERTINA;
    int y = 0;
    int w = LARGHEZZACOPERTINA;
    int h = ALTEZZACOPERTINA;
    int riga = 0;
    int indexriga = 0;
    int testindex = 0;

    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        testindex = NRCopertineVerticale;
    }
    else {
        testindex = NRCopertineOrizzontale;
    }

    for (NSDictionary *rigaordine in ElencoOrdini)
    {

        if (indexriga > 0) x = x + OFFSETXCOPERTINA + w;
        y = OFFSETYCOPERTINA + (riga * (h + OFFSETYCOPERTINA));

        UIButton *buttonCopertina = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        buttonCopertina.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

        [buttonCopertina setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255.0) green:(255/255.0) blue:(0/255.0) alpha:0.3]];

        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@image.php?CODe=%@", URLXXX, [rigaordine objectForKey:@"cod_isb"]]]]];

        UIImageView *copertina = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
        [copertina setTag:TAGCopertine + index];
        [copertina setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];

        [buttonCopertina setTag:TAGButtonCopertine + index];
        [buttonCopertina addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonCopertinaClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [scrollView addSubview:copertina];
        [scrollView addSubview:buttonCopertina];

        index++;
        indexriga++;

        if (indexriga >= testindex) {
            indexriga = 0;
            riga++;
            x = 10;
        }

    }
```

when I rotate the iPad:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    int index = 0;
    int x = OFFSETXCOPERTINA;
    int y = 0;
    int w = LARGHEZZACOPERTINA;
    int h = ALTEZZACOPERTINA;
    int riga = 0;
    int indexriga = 0;
    int testindex = 0;

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        testindex = NRCopertineVerticale;
    }
    else {
        testindex = NRCopertineOrizzontale;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j< 999; j++) {
        if (indexriga > 0) x = x + OFFSETXCOPERTINA + w;
        y = OFFSETYCOPERTINA + (riga * (h + OFFSETYCOPERTINA));

        UIImageView *copertina = (UIImageView *)[self.scrollView viewWithTag:(TAGCopertine + j)];
        if (copertina != nil) {
            copertina.frame = CGRectMake( x, y, LARGHEZZACOPERTINA, ALTEZZACOPERTINA );
        }

        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.scrollView viewWithTag:(TAGButtonCopertine + j)];
        if (button != nil) {
            button.frame = CGRectMake( x, y, LARGHEZZACOPERTINA, ALTEZZACOPERTINA );
        }

        index++;
        indexriga++;

        if (indexriga >= testindex) {
            indexriga = 0;
            riga++;
            x = 10;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What's the relationship between the UIButton and the UIScrollView?

Comment: How're you adding imageView and buttons show your code and also how're you changing the button's frame ?

Comment: can you post the screen shot in vertical e orizontal positions?

Comment: I can't post image becouse I'm a new user sorry.
the screen is very clear, there are a matrix of image, every image has a traspanent button over.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your are setting some incorrect frame of the button and it goes offscreen. The correct approach here is to create a `UIView` subclass, that has a `UIImageView` and a `UIButton` inside it. Expose a property for setting and the image and create a `delegate` for touching the button. Then, instantiate your view with button, set an image, set its delegate and add it as subview of the `UIScrollView` and change only the frame of your view with button - everything will reposition accordingly.

Comment: the frame is correct, if I don't change the UIImageView frame the button change the position correctly.

Comment: I've try this way. I've the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

After thousand of test the only way I've find is to change position of UIImageViews in the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation.

and after change the UIButtons position in the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation.

This doesn't seem to have explanations but it works.